# How to run multiple discord.py bots concurrently with different bot tokens?

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I'm trying to create a Discord bot application using discord.py, where I need to run 5 different bots concurrently. I have all the bot tokens stored in a list variable named `BOT_TOKENS`.

I've set up my bot instances and event handlers, but I'm unsure about how to run all bots concurrently using their respective tokens. I'm aware that the `bot.run(token)` method is blocking, so I can't simply call it multiple times sequentially. I've been trying to use `asyncio` to run the bots concurrently, but I'm having difficulties getting it to work correctly.

Can anyone provide an example or guidance on how to achieve running discord.py bots concurrently with different tokens from a list?

Here's the basic structure of my bot setup:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

BOT_TOKENS = ["token1", "token2", "token3", "token4", "token5"]


# Define event handlers and commands for all bots
def create_bot(token):
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=f"!", intents=intents)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f"{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!")

    return bot

bots = [create_bot(token) for token in BOT_TOKENS]

# I need help with running all 5 bots concurrently here.
### cannot call bots[0].run() as this is blocking
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok here's how to run the loop

```py
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
bots = [create_bot(token) for token in DISCORD_TOKENS.values()]
tasks = [loop.create_task(run_bot(bot, token)) for bot, token in zip(bots, DISCORD_TOKENS.values())]

loop.run_forever()
```

so a complete answer would be

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()

BOT_TOKENS = ["token1", "token2", "token3", "token4", "token5"]


# Define event handlers and commands for all bots
def create_bot(token):
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=f"!", intents=intents)

    @bot.event
    async def on_ready():
        print(f"{bot.user.name} has connected to Discord!")

    return bot

bots = [create_bot(token) for token in BOT_TOKENS]

# run all bots
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
tasks = [loop.create_task(run_bot(bot, token)) for bot, token in zip(bots, DISCORD_TOKENS.values())]

loop.run_forever()
```